# Form Opacity windows xp .net 2

Tags: .net

Do anyone knows why this function doesnt work in Windows XP. works fine under win7

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    double flt = double.Parse("0,55");
    ShowOpacity(flt);
}


private void ShowOpacity(double flt)
{
    this.Opacity = flt;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some more details about your environment? Are you running Windows XP in a virtual machine? Which one? What kind of graphics card/driver does the computer have? This code has definitely worked for me in the past under Windows XP.

Comment: Im running this code in an virtual machine. thank you.

Comment: It's likely that that's your problem then. I don't have a VM handy to test right now, so I can't say for sure. Some of them may have good enough video drivers to support this, but it's far from guaranteed—for example, layered windows are known not to work with Terminal Server. Expect that it will work properly on a real Windows XP client.

Comment: Why are you parsing a string instead of just using the numeric value? One reason this could break is if your VM didn't have its locale set to one where comma is used as a decimal point.

Comment: if I just type this.Opacity = .55; it works ok. but if i parse the value which it comes from the setting file (an text file), it doesnot works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I just type this.Opacity = .55; it works ok.

Your virtual machine is running with the wrong system locale, not the Netherlands.  Which is where I think you're from.  Unfortunately, "0,55" is a valid value for a string in locations like the USA, the comma is treated like a thousands separator.  The result of the Parse statement is 55, a value that the Opacity property silently truncates to 1 without raising an exception.

Control Panel + Regional and Language Options, switch your machine to your home country.  Check the "Decimal Symbol" setting in the Formats tab, Advanced afterwards to verify it is a comma and not a period.  Also check the type for the Setting, you want a double, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN - [Form.Opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx):

> Windows 2000, Windows 2000 Professional, Windows 2000 Server, Windows 2000 Advanced Server, Windows XP Home Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows Server 2003 Platform Note: Supports the Layered Windows API. This property has no effect on platforms that cannot display layered windows. In addition, some display drivers do not support layering.

So, the issue may very well be with your display driver.

Comment: The important part of that is about display drivers. If you're running this in an XP virtual machine, that might be why you don't see transparency. Otherwise, it's saying that layered windows (which this property uses under the covers) *are* supported in Windows XP.